# Restore alsa configuration?

Tags: alsa, debian

I am not able to restore alsa configuration. Please help.

I am **storing** the current configuration as

```
sudo alsactl --file asound.state store
```

I am **trying to re-store** the same configuration as

```
sudo alsactl --file asound.state restore
```

But no effect is taking place.

Comment: What effect did you expect?

Comment: To restore to the state of "asound.state" file. But it isn't restoring at all. In general I am disabling speaker and enabling headset using amixer commands, saving the file amd trying to restore it on reboot. But I am not getting the same effect as the amixer commands.

Comment: Do you see the desired value in `asound.state`?

Comment: Ok, I changed manually the asound.state file and restored it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I did as follows and it worked for me.

**Store** sound card settings.

```
sudo alsactl --file asound.state store
```

**Edit** asound.state file as per my requirement (eg. disabling speaker and enabling headset).

**Copy** the edited asound.state on the original configuration file.

```
cp asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
```

**Reboot** the system. And it worked.

I am still confused that when I used amixer commnads to disable speaker and enable headset, and after that I Store the configuration to asound.state file, then why I am getting the original configuration instead I should get the changed configuration with speaker disabled and headset enabled?

Answer (score 0):

To save alsa setting, use following command.

> sudo alsactl store

To verify the setting is saved you can check the file 'asound.state' which is stored at location /var/lib/alsa/asound.state (use locate command if you want to know the location of the file in your system)

To restore the alsa setting, use following command

> sudo alsactl restore